# Android USB only charges on Ubuntu 20.04/Windows 10 dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows-10, android

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04LTS on my hp laptop with a windows 10 dual boot. All USB devices work fine but when I plug in my phone to the laptop the prompt to select USB options does not appear. I tried doing a fresh Ubuntu install but it doesn't work. I tried various cables and phones so I'm certain it's not a phone or cable issue because they work on my friends laptop that has Ubuntu 20.04 too. The windows installation works fine.Please help.
I have also noticed that when I suspend and the power the laptop when the device is plugged in, the prompt will appear.

Comment: Do you see anything USB-related when you wipe down from the top edge?

Comment: No I don't see anything but when I suspend and turn it on again with the phone plugged it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution to this. It seems the auto-suspend setting was causing this problem. I just deactivated it as follows.
Open a terminal window and input:

```
 cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

This should return a value of 2, which means autosuspend is enabled. You can fix this by editing the grub file. Enter:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change this to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

Press Ctrl + X to save the file, and exit. Next, update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

When that completes, restart Ubuntu.

After rebooting, log into your account and enter the cat command again:

```
cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

This time, the value returned should be -1. You've disabled autosuspend, so USB devices connected to your laptop should not fail due to power issues.